# How to increment a value in Javascript with a value the user defines

Tags: javascript, for-loop, increment

I want to write a loop that will display numbers from 1-100 in multiples that the user picks.

Here's my JS code.

```
 var x = prompt("Enter the increment you want to see")

   for (i=0;i<=100;i=i+x) {
    document.write(i+"</br>")
   }
```

For example, if I enter "10" I want the code to print the numbers 10, 20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100

Why does this not work?

I am teaching myself Javascript, and I am going crazy trying to figure this out.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse x. The following code should work -

```js
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter the increment you want to see"));

for (i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + x) {
  document.write(i + " </br>");
}
```

Comment: Probably more efficient to parse it once at the beginning instead of each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The returned value from `prompt` is string. You need to parse it as a number (with the radix value as stated in the comments):

```
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter the increment you want to see"), 10);
```

Comment: Worth noting that it's [still recommended to use the radix parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) when using `parseInt`, at least for the time being.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll never forget that prompt returns a string value.